# Calling HTTPS Web Service from iOS Application

Tags: ios, web-services

I can call the HTTP web service but when the same service is HTTPS it throws error that it cannot be called. I am invoking it from iOS application. Do I need to pass some additional header fields related to HTTPS.

UPDATE (SOLUTION):

Seems like it just needed the HOST header parameter.

Comment: Hi I am Also Facing the Same problem How can you solved it . WIll You Plz Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not passing any authorization parameters in any way to the service and it is just a url: "https://www.xxxxxx.com/dev/tools/search=?" the issue is from server side authentication certificate. they need to allow the request to be taken in from server's end by configuring server authentication certificate.

Comment: I have made an ios app and in that all the webservices are secure.In that case if i hit a webservice using nsmutablerequest i am getting status code as 200 but response data is not received at user end,I have also set timeoutperiod but it is not affected